# How to parse span tags within a <td> as separate values via python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

So my HTML kind of looks like this with many rows following similar formatting:

```html
<table class>
<thead class="ant-table-thead">
<tr>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">ID</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Title</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
            </div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Date</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Server</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Lunch Menu</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Lunch Unique ID</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">State</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
            </div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Invitees</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class="ant-table-align-center ant-table-row-cell-last" style="text-align: center;"><span
            class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title"></span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0" data-row-key="1603">
    <td class="">1603</td>
    <td class="">Lunch Invite</td>
    <td class=""><span>11 Dec, 20:30</span></td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">Prebooked</span></td>
    <td class="">Vegan menu</td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">648898</span></td>
    <td class="">INIT</td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">Samuel P</span><span class="ant-tag">Enrique Ortuno</span><span
            class="ant-tag">Michelle Jones</span><span class="ant-tag">Bob Hueman</span><span class="ant-tag">Joshua
            Flawr</span><span class="ant-tag">Guilherme Caixeta</span></td>
    <td class="" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: flex;"><button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
                style="min-width: 165px;"><span>Start Lunch</span></button><button type="button" class="ant-btn"
                style="margin-left: 10px;"><span>Update</span></button><button type="button" class="ant-btn"
                style="margin-left: 10px;"><span>Cancel</span></button></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

While trying to scrape it, all the span values within one `<td>` are combined into one single value making it indistinguishable that where the first value ends and second starts. For example the invitees for the lunch make one large name. I tried to split via `.isupper()` check to see where a name ends and another one begins but some people would put in all caps making it impossible to know via similar logic. Similarly Start Lunch, Update and Cancel all come in together to form a single value.

What I tried:

1. pandas: `pd.read_html(open('sample.html').read())[0]`
2. BS4:

Code:

```
#def get_inner():
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = open('sample.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
onvista_table = soup
clean_data = []
for i in range (0,len(onvista_table.find_all('table'))):
        table =  onvista_table.find_all('table')[i]
        for tool_tip_span in table.find_all('span',{"class":"INFO_LAYER_CONTAINER"}):
            tool_tip_span.decompose()
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            raw_data = []
            for cell in row.find_all(['td','th']):
                raw_data.append(cell.get_text().strip())
            if len(raw_data)<9:
                print(raw_data)
raw_data
```

Both codes work fine with above html sample is treated as contents of `sample.html`. But the issue is same, both won't let me parse them as separate entries BS4 one won't let me parse these as separately. Neither the `pd.read_html()` but the function seems to return the same result and there is no support for span tags inside function. Is there a way I can know these values separately. I just want them separately so any help like parsing them as a list or adding a separate row for each span thing are also appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want to have separate? And do you mind sharing the code you're attempting this with?

Comment: Added the code and what I want separate is the span elements entries within a single `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question - A thing could be improved is your expected Output

But as understood, that you want to seperate all `span` text you can just loop over each cell again to `cell.find_all('span')` and its text.

**Solution could be**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = """
<table class>
<thead class="ant-table-thead">
<tr>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">ID</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Title</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
            </div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Date</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Server</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Lunch Menu</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Lunch Unique ID</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">State</span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span>
            </div>
        </span></th>
    <th class=""><span class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title">Invitees</span><span
                    class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
    <th class="ant-table-align-center ant-table-row-cell-last" style="text-align: center;"><span
            class="ant-table-header-column">
            <div><span class="ant-table-column-title"></span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
        </span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0" data-row-key="1603">
    <td class="">1603</td>
    <td class="">Lunch Invite</td>
    <td class=""><span>11 Dec, 20:30</span></td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">Prebooked</span></td>
    <td class="">Vegan menu</td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">648898</span></td>
    <td class="">INIT</td>
    <td class=""><span class="ant-tag">Samuel P</span><span class="ant-tag">Enrique Ortuno</span><span
            class="ant-tag">Michelle Jones</span><span class="ant-tag">Bob Hueman</span><span class="ant-tag">Joshua
            Flawr</span><span class="ant-tag">Guilherme Caixeta</span></td>
    <td class="" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: flex;"><button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
                style="min-width: 165px;"><span>Start Lunch</span></button><button type="button" class="ant-btn"
                style="margin-left: 10px;"><span>Update</span></button><button type="button" class="ant-btn"
                style="margin-left: 10px;"><span>Cancel</span></button></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
onvista_table = soup
clean_data = []
for i in range (0,len(onvista_table.find_all('table'))):
        table =  onvista_table.find_all('table')[i]
        for tool_tip_span in table.find_all('span',{"class":"INFO_LAYER_CONTAINER"}):
            tool_tip_span.decompose()
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            raw_data = []
            for cell in row.find_all(['td','th']):
                
                if len(cell.find_all('span')) > 1:
                    span_data = []
                    for span in cell.find_all('span'):
                        span_data.append(span.get_text())
                    raw_data.append(span_data)               
                else:
                    raw_data.append(cell.get_text().strip())
                
            if len(raw_data)<9:
                print(raw_data)
raw_data
```

**Output with clustered Information based on your example, it my looks prettier as dictionary**

```
['1603',
 'Lunch Invite',
 '11 Dec, 20:30',
 'Prebooked',
 'Vegan menu',
 '648898',
 'INIT',
 ['Samuel P',
  'Enrique Ortuno',
  'Michelle Jones',
  'Bob Hueman',
  'Joshua\n            Flawr',
  'Guilherme Caixeta'],
 ['Start Lunch', 'Update', 'Cancel']]
```